# Why can't i create models in my project and that and it throws me an error called type error?

Tags: php, laravel

I receive this when I want to make a migration or create model or anything in the project bit I can't. I don't know  if its the nexw version of laravel like it's been a while since I've touched the project it's been a while.

I receive this :

```
TypeError 

  Carbon\Carbon::setLastErrors(): Argument #1 ($lastErrors) must be of type array, bool given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php on line 98

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php:928
    924▕      * @param array $lastErrors
    925▕      *
    926▕      * @return void
    927▕      */
  ➜ 928▕     private static function setLastErrors(array $lastErrors)
    929▕     {
    930▕         static::$lastErrors = $lastErrors;
    931▕     }
    932▕

   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException 

  Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\MergeConflictSolutionProvider.php:52
     48▕     }
     49▕
     50▕     protected function getCurrentBranch(string $directory): string
     51▕     {
  ➜  52▕         $branch = "'".trim(shell_exec("cd ${directory}; git branch | grep \\* | cut -d ' ' -f2"))."'";
     53▕
     54▕         if ($branch === "''") {
     55▕             $branch = 'current branch';
     56▕         }
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Whoops\Exception\ErrorException: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\MergeConflictSolutionProvider.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): Whoops\Run->handleError(8192, 'Using ${var} in...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 52)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Facade\\Ignition...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository.php(50): class_implements('Facade\\Ignition...')
#5 [internal function]: Facade\Ignition\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository->Facade\Ignition\SolutionProviders\{closure}('Facade\\Ignition...', 10)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Arr.php(717): array_filter(Array, Object(Closure), 1)        
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Collection.php(358): Illuminate\Support\Arr::where(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository.php(49): Illuminate\Support\Collection->filter(Object(Closure))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Adapters\Laravel\IgnitionSolutionsRepository.php(36): Facade\Ignition\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository->getSolutionsForThrowable(Object(Whoops\Exception\ErrorException))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Writer.php(244): NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\IgnitionSolutionsRepository->getFromThrowable(Object(Whoops\Exception\ErrorException))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Writer.php(123): NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer->renderSolution(Object(Whoops\Exception\Inspector))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Handler.php(39): NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer->write(Object(Whoops\Exception\Inspector))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Run.php(370): NunoMaduro\Collision\Handler->handle(Object(Whoops\Exception\ErrorException))
#14 [internal function]: Whoops\Run->handleException(Object(Whoops\Exception\ErrorException))
#15 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\MergeConflictSolutionProvider.php on line 52

   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 

  Uncaught Whoops\Exception\ErrorException: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\MergeConflictSolutionProvider.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): Whoops\Run->handleError(8192, 'Using ${var} in...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 52)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Facade\\Ignition...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository.php(50): class_implements('Facade\\Ignition...')
#5 [internal function]: Facade\Ignition\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository->Facade\Ignition\SolutionProviders\{closure}('Facade\\Ignition...', 10)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Arr.php(717): array_filter(Array, Object(Closure), 1)        
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Collection.php(358): Illuminate\Support\Arr::where(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository.php(49): Illuminate\Support\Collection->filter(Object(Closure))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Adapters\Laravel\IgnitionSolutionsRepository.php(36): Facade\Ignition\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository->getSolutionsForThrowable(Object(Whoops\Exception\ErrorException))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Writer.php(244): NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\IgnitionSolutionsRepository->getFromThrowable(Object(Whoops\Exception\ErrorException))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Writer.php(123): NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer->renderSolution(Object(Whoops\Exception\Inspector))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Handler.php(39): NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer->write(Object(Whoops\Exception\Inspector))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Run.php(370): NunoMaduro\Collision\Handler->handle(Object(Whoops\Exception\ErrorException))
#14 [internal function]: Whoops\Run->handleException(Object(Whoops\Exception\ErrorException))
#15 {main}
  thrown

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\MergeConflictSolutionProvider.php:52
     48▕     }
     49▕
     50▕     protected function getCurrentBranch(string $directory): string
     51▕     {
  ➜  52▕         $branch = "'".trim(shell_exec("cd ${directory}; git branch | grep \\* | cut -d ' ' -f2"))."'";
     53▕
     54▕         if ($branch === "''") {
     55▕             $branch = 'current branch';
     56▕         }
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Whoops\Exception\ErrorException: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\MergeConflictSolutionProvider.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): Whoops\Run->handleError(8192, 'Using ${var} in...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 52)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Facade\\Ignition...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository.php(50): class_implements('Facade\\Ignition...')
#5 [internal function]: Facade\Ignition\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository->Facade\Ignition\SolutionProviders\{closure}('Facade\\Ignition...', 10)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Arr.php(717): array_filter(Array, Object(Closure), 1)        
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Collection.php(358): Illuminate\Support\Arr::where(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository.php(49): Illuminate\Support\Collection->filter(Object(Closure))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Adapters\Laravel\IgnitionSolutionsRepository.php(36): Facade\Ignition\SolutionProviders\SolutionProviderRepository->getSolutionsForThrowable(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Writer.php(244): NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\IgnitionSolutionsRepository->getFromThrowable(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Writer.php(123): NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer->renderSolution(Object(NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\Inspector))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Handler.php(39): NunoMaduro\Collision\Writer->write(Object(NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\Inspector))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Adapters\Laravel\ExceptionHandler.php(72): NunoMaduro\Collision\Handler->handle()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(185): NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\ExceptionHandler->renderForConsole(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderForConsole(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(209): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#18 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetsoutenance\vendor\facade\ignition\src\SolutionProviders\MergeConflictSolutionProvider.php on line 52
```

I receive this when I want to make a migration or create model or anything in the project bit I can't. I don't know  if its the nexw version of laravel like it's been a while since I've touched the project it's been a while.

Why that ? Thanks for the help

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Run `composer update`, [this issue was fixed 2 weeks ago](https://github.com/facade/ignition/pull/471)

Answer (score -1):

For solving this issue only one things has to be done in

in this path got to line number 928 :
\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php

change this
" private static function setLastErrors(array $lastErrors) "
to this
" private static function setLastErrors($lastErrors) "